# How to adapt the layer only in the limit area allowed in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-android

I want to implement an automatic cropping function, when the user makes a layer outside the limit area and saves it, an automatic cropping will be done, I am using the react-native-mapbox library, and I am trying to implement something, I will leave the code that most It helped me get close to the bottom, but it ended up not being enough, does anyone have any ideas to solve this type of problem? I'm going to attach images to explain the idea better. Thanks guys!

```
const polygon = [
    [
        -43.005534926999964,
        -21.080226593000024
    ],
    [
        -43.00556559399994,
        -21.08049579099996
    ],
    [
        -43.00580549899998,
        -21.08062041499993
    ],
    [
        -43.00622949299995,
        -21.081063803999914
    ],
    [
        -43.00630497600001,
        -21.081371809999975
    ],
    [
        -43.00627922299995,
        -21.081567591999885
    ],
    [
        -43.006274747,
        -21.0818983499999
    ],
    [
        -43.00631987799986,
        -21.08234467999984
    ],
    [
        -43.006303817999864,
        -21.082764598000075
    ],
    [
        -43.00629931699994,
        -21.083165747999747
    ],
    [
        -43.00629770799997,
        -21.083577543999848
    ],
    [
        -43.006259353,
        -21.083792036000023
    ],
    [
        -43.00608749499995,
        -21.084081566999927
    ],
    [
        -43.006012527999985,
        -21.084328123
    ],
    [
        -43.005836041999835,
        -21.08459893799993
    ],
    [
        -43.005626943,
        -21.084895660000104
    ],
    [
        -43.00515581299989,
        -21.085085654999904
    ],
    [
        -43.00479303099997,
        -21.084955388000022
    ],
    [
        -43.00498200299999,
        -21.08612217399994
    ],
    [
        -43.00527727128426,
        -21.087836704335828
    ],
    [
        -43.0042229312937,
        -21.087855928793303
    ],
    [
        -43.003654548477556,
        -21.08784146914388
    ],
    [
        -43.0027679526737,
        -21.088407023673252
    ],
    [
        -43.002507208958754,
        -21.0883989978549
    ],
    [
        -43.00174188859754,
        -21.0888603704384
    ],
    [
        -43.0021566343191,
        -21.089561124438784
    ],
    [
        -43.00242225169635,
        -21.09020321967628
    ],
    [
        -43.003658805409046,
        -21.090757855947636
    ],
    [
        -43.002636067431744,
        -21.09198367714026
    ],
    [
        -43.000778743245554,
        -21.094184614550247
    ],
    [
        -43.00095755332289,
        -21.095581787736293
    ],
    [
        -43.00154425173108,
        -21.095431712238575
    ],
    [
        -43.00233016046536,
        -21.095037831134796
    ],
    [
        -43.002854128551874,
        -21.09510512567872
    ],
    [
        -43.003364703020814,
        -21.095294540485803
    ],
    [
        -43.00371810133358,
        -21.09522310573785
    ],
    [
        -43.004292559775166,
        -21.09519484286128
    ],
    [
        -43.00480672745813,
        -21.09513516794222
    ],
    [
        -43.005064158636515,
        -21.09502782731965
    ],
    [
        -43.00537870270281,
        -21.094857862406606
    ],
    [
        -43.00634435336424,
        -21.094030021295385
    ],
    [
        -43.00751108340524,
        -21.09342829394651
    ],
    [
        -43.00790591399989,
        -21.092997538999903
    ],
    [
        -43.00808442600001,
        -21.092975922999976
    ],
    [
        -43.00899157100001,
        -21.09272542099996
    ],
    [
        -43.009636278999906,
        -21.09262215199988
    ],
    [
        -43.010185031999946,
        -21.092641311000044
    ],
    [
        -43.01089424282121,
        -21.092580988022757
    ],
    [
        -43.0109444095685,
        -21.09255743630206
    ],
    [
        -43.011459495999894,
        -21.092190038000034
    ],
    [
        -43.011946607,
        -21.092038724999895
    ],
    [
        -43.01324080499998,
        -21.091455306999872
    ],
    [
        -43.01493977099985,
        -21.0907684960001
    ],
    [
        -43.01539250699984,
        -21.090519695000047
    ],
    [
        -43.01569208712482,
        -21.090297175991985
    ],
    [
        -43.015692767,
        -21.090296671000033
    ],
    [
        -43.015838182266464,
        -21.090292753092385
    ],
    [
        -43.01595858499996,
        -21.09028950899986
    ],
    [
        -43.016442072999986,
        -21.090109411000018
    ],
    [
        -43.01684033999992,
        -21.089810834999913
    ],
    [
        -43.01717671870549,
        -21.089590695640776
    ],
    [
        -43.01718497099994,
        -21.0895852949999
    ],
    [
        -43.01719999899997,
        -21.089448160000106
    ],
    [
        -43.01720952801087,
        -21.0893120985213
    ],
    [
        -43.017211137999844,
        -21.08928910999998
    ],
    [
        -43.017409409,
        -21.089304927999876
    ],
    [
        -43.01784620286903,
        -21.089388043148258
    ],
    [
        -43.01786066999985,
        -21.08939079599996
    ],
    [
        -43.017700484999956,
        -21.08827753500006
    ],
    [
        -43.01766122657581,
        -21.088085759792847
    ],
    [
        -43.01758927799987,
        -21.08773429400005
    ],
    [
        -43.01756486799999,
        -21.087302582999985
    ],
    [
        -43.01759904209369,
        -21.087159172836405
    ],
    [
        -43.01765821699998,
        -21.086910847000038
    ],
    [
        -43.01765633803302,
        -21.086903186718963
    ],
    [
        -43.0171014998199,
        -21.084641161214808
    ],
    [
        -43.01696336500002,
        -21.084077989
    ],
    [
        -43.01694106561828,
        -21.08384489236287
    ],
    [
        -43.016940444999854,
        -21.083838404999867
    ],
    [
        -43.01693709702122,
        -21.0838371755394
    ],
    [
        -43.0165471570181,
        -21.083693979367393
    ],
    [
        -43.01620159500001,
        -21.083567079
    ],
    [
        -43.01551535899984,
        -21.083252509000026
    ],
    [
        -43.014728853999834,
        -21.08261620400011
    ],
    [
        -43.014360132726544,
        -21.082065501826996
    ],
    [
        -43.01435838599994,
        -21.08206289299984
    ],
    [
        -43.01401013128298,
        -21.081973898601955
    ],
    [
        -43.01368943699996,
        -21.081889964999867
    ],
    [
        -43.01367521223802,
        -21.081888311295543
    ],
    [
        -43.01365349299987,
        -21.08188276100005
    ],
    [
        -43.01356664796623,
        -21.08187569007993
    ],
    [
        -43.013026582999885,
        -21.08183171700002
    ],
    [
        -43.011993625999835,
        -21.081464385999812
    ],
    [
        -43.01149014499999,
        -21.08131762
    ],
    [
        -43.01103667369691,
        -21.081232946370875
    ],
    [
        -43.010908103,
        -21.081208938999932
    ],
    [
        -43.010693909932954,
        -21.081124159569605
    ],
    [
        -43.01039643999997,
        -21.080986747999837
    ],
    [
        -43.0099210935571,
        -21.080818269339584
    ],
    [
        -43.009899867679245,
        -21.080809867810437
    ],
    [
        -43.009886995999956,
        -21.080804772999965
    ],
    [
        -43.00917488899996,
        -21.080659256999823
    ],
    [
        -43.00822322600003,
        -21.080355462999986
    ],
    [
        -43.007890099999926,
        -21.080342521
    ],
    [
        -43.00715798299993,
        -21.08023307499988
    ],
    [
        -43.005534926999964,
        -21.080226593000024
    ]
]

const point: [number, number] = [
  -43.00168630538215,
  -21.095885894840052
]

// [
//     -43.006044642470016,
//     -21.080229402319773
// ]

  function isInsideLimit(point: [number, number], polygon: Array<[number, number]>) {
    const n = polygon.length
    let isIn = false
    const x = point[0]
    const y = point[1]
    let x1, x2, y1, y2

    x1 = polygon[n - 1][0]
    y1 = polygon[n - 1][1]

    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      x2 = polygon[i][0];
      y2 = polygon[i][1];

      if (y < y1 !== y < y2 && x < (x2 - x1) * (y - y1) / (y2 - y1) + x1) {
        isIn = !isIn;
      }
        console.log({y, y1, y2, x, x1, x2})
      x1 = x2
      y1 = y2
    }

    return isIn;
  }

  console.log(isInsideLimit(point, polygon))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]